# How to add modules from torchtext.data?

Tags: python, pytorch, torchtext

I'm trying to do this `from torchtext.data import TabularDataset, Field, LabelField, BucketIterator`, however, I get the following exception:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'TabularDataset' from 'torchtext.data' (D:\Users\shuvo\miniconda3\envs\vi38\lib\site-packages\torchtext\data_*init*_.py)

But I see it in the documentation (figure below). Is there any other way to import it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`torchtext.data` and its contents have been obsolete for a big while now (readthedocs are grossly outdated). For a time being, it's been available as `torchtext.legacy.data`, but it has been removed entirely in the recent versions as far as I know, in a favour of modern torchdata routines, such as [`torchdata.datapipes.iter.CSVParser`](https://pytorch.org/data/main/generated/torchdata.datapipes.iter.CSVParser.html).